# Showing the keyboard when my Editbox, contained in a Dialog, is focused

Tags: android

I am trying to find a way to get my keyboard to show when my EditBox is inside a custom Dialog.

```
this.getDialog().setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            this.getDialog().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
            this.getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

This piece of code is executed, but the keyboard isn't showing up. Forcing the display with `SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE`displays the keyboard **behind** the dialog, which is useless.

Maybe I need to point out that my dialog is created like this:

```
public MyDialog(Context context, int layout) {
    this._layout = layout;
    this._context = context;
    this._rootView = ((Activity) this._context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(this._layout, null);
    this._dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this._context).setView(this._rootView).create();
}
```

`layout` is a reference to one of my layouts in my layout directory

I tried almost all the possible solutions that I could find on Stack Overflow but none of them seems to work correctly. If anyone has an idea, I'll be glad to try!

Comment: Saying honestly, If I have en EditText no matter - in dialog, Activity, Fragment - it automatically gains focus on start and show keyboard. Did you tried to force requestFocus() for this item?

Comment: @GoltsevEugene Requesting focus does not do anything, the keyboard is still not showing up

Comment: Okay, maybe it's not so good idea, but you can also try DialogFragment or even your custom Fragment with Dialog behaviour.